# Swift: Using getter with no value

Tags: swift

What is the benefit of using a getter with no value. For example:

```
protocol xyz:Class{
 var uuid:UUID{get}
}
```

I'll really appreciate your thoughts.

Comment: It's just a protocol declaration. The class which adopts the protocol must implement the property at least with the getter returning a value. Btw: According to the naming convention protocol names are supposed to start with a capital letter and the `class` constraint is lowercased.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code in your question is declaring a protocol. A protocol is basically a contract. It provides no functionality.

Your protocol's contract is stating that whatever conforms to the protocol must, at a minimum, provide a getter for a variable named `uuid` with a type of `UUID`.

The protocol itself does not provide the getter so it does not return a value. The class/struct/enum that conforms to the protocol will provide a value from the getter. This same class/struct/enum may also (if desired) provide a setter for the `uuid` variable as well. The protocol only states there must be a getter but it does not preclude the possibility of a setter.

The [Protocols chapter](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-ID267) in the Swift book shows examples and provides much more information on this. Specifically, the [Property Requirements](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-ID267) section covers protocol properties.